# Is there any way to write classname of "hasClass()" as 'starts with smt' in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to write jquery code like :

```
if($('label').hasClass('info_')) {

}
```

There are many class names like : info_1, info_2 ,info_3  etc. So , I must write that, if label has a classname which starts info_; do something.

But I looked jquery site and searched hasClass(). There is no example about this. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using :

```
  $("[class^=info_]"); //Classes Starts with  info_
  $('[class*=info_]');  // Classes which contains info_
```

As per your code instead of `hasClass`

```
if($('label').is('[class*=info_]')){} //Contains
```

or

```
 if($('label').is('[class^=info_]')){} //Starts with
```

Comment: Note that this does not work for elements that have multiple classes as the class^ syntax just checks the string that is the list of classes, rather than checking each class individually.

Comment: you should use `$('label').is('[class^="info_"], [class*=" info_"]')` to test for both cases (note there's a space in front of `info_` for the 'contains' selector ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `hasClass`, but you can use `filter`.  You can go through the classes, and find the ones that match.

```
var $labels = $('label').filter(function(){
    return /\b(info_\d+)\b/.test(this.className);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if( /(^|\s)info_/.test( $('label')[0].className ) ) {

}
```

or if you have multiple labels:

```
if ($("label").is(function() {
    return /(^|\s)info_/.test(this.className);
})) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An element can have multiple `class` values (separated with spaces). So use something like this:

```
<label class="has_info info_1">...</label>
```

And then you can do this:

```
if ( $('label').hasClass('has_info')
{
    // ...
}
```

EDIT: the "begins with" CSS selector is probably the better route here. What follows is still true however.

Though I do think that `$(label).hasClass()` is a bad idea. You probably want something like this:

```
$('label').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('has_info') )
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: that's an overshoot - you don't need to introduce new classes

Comment: Yeah, I see that from the other answers; I forgot about the attribute CSS selector. Still, I think the bit about the `each` function is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below code if you want to check if class namme starts with...
 You want to check the classes that starts with myclass- ,so it would give you the number of occurrence according to your input in the alert.
    According to this the output is 2.

```
<div class="myclass-s1"></div>
<div class="myclass-b10"></div>
<div class="myclassb10"></div>

$.expr[':'].hasClassStartingWithInput = function(obj){
return ((/\bmyclass-/).test(obj.className)); //here is the input(myclass-)that you need to give
 };
```